# $(t\mapsto t^ae^{bt} )_{a\in \mathbb{R}_+,b\in\mathbb{R}}$ is linearly independent of $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: vector-spaces

We consider the family  $F=(t\mapsto t^ae^{bt} )_{a\in \mathbb{R}_+,b\in\mathbb{R}}$ of functions of space $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$.
Show that $F$  is linearly independent of $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

An idea please.

Comment: For an arbitrary positive real $a$, the formula $t\mapsto t^a$ is not well-defined as a function $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ (e.g. consider $a=1/2$, $t=-1$). Did you mean to consider real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}_+$?

Comment: @JulianRosen Note that $a>0$ above. Look closely at the family $F$.

Comment: Perhaps the Wronskian will work.

Comment: @GEdgar Can you give this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some details omitted:

Suppose $\sum_k \alpha_k t^{a_k}e^{t b_k} = 0$ for all $t$.

Order the $(a_k,b_k)$ such that $(a,b) < (c,d)$ if $b<d$ or $b=d$ and $a<c$.

By reordering we can suppose that the $(a_k,b_k)$ are in increasing order.

Consider ${1 \over t^{a_n}e^{t b_n}} \sum_k \alpha_k t^{a_k}e^{t b_k} $ and let $t \to \infty$, this shows that $\alpha_n = 0$.

Rinse & repeat.